# How to draw polylines from a set of points from a XML file?

Tags: python, xml, opencv, polyline

I need to draw a contour in my image, so I used the function `cv2.polylines` to draw lines between points, but I don't know why I have an error like `d` is not defined (`d` is a list containing the set of points `(x, y)`).

```py
import xml.dom.minidom
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main(file):
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
    values = doc.getElementsByTagName("coordinateIndex")
    coordX = doc.getElementsByTagName("x")
    coordY = doc.getElementsByTagName("y")
    d = {}
    for atr_value, atr_x, atr_y in zip(values, coordX, coordY):
        value = atr_value.getAttribute('value')
        x = atr_x.getAttribute('value')
        y = atr_y.getAttribute('value')
        d[value] = [x, y]
    return d
image = cv2.imread('1.631791322.58809740.14.834982.40440.3641459051.955.6373933.1920.jpeg')
point=d
cv2.polylines(image, 
              point, 
              isClosed = False,
              color = (0,255,0),
              thickness = 3, 
              linetype = cv2.LINE_AA)
imshow("image",image)

result = main('1.631791322.58809740.14.834982.40440.3641459051.955.6373933.1920.xml')
print(result)
```

That's a sample XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TwoDimensionSpatialCoordinate>
    <coordinateIndex value="0"/>
        <x value="302.6215607602997"/>
        <y value="166.6285651861381"/>
    <coordinateIndex value="1"/>
        <x value="3.6215607602997"/>
        <y value="1.6285651861381"/>
</TwoDimensionSpatialCoordinate>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

First of all, you create a dictionary `d` by `d = {}` resp. `d[value] = [x, y]`, i.e. `d` is **not** a list.

Second, "`d` is not defined", since `d` is a local variable in your `main` method. When you call `result = main(...)`, then `result` would reflect the value of `d`.

Third, `cv2.polylines` expects a NumPy array of integer pairs. You have float values, stored as strings in your XML.

So, now let's find a way to fix these issues: First of all, we cast your coordinates to `float` (and rename your method, since `main` is a bad choice for such a function):

```py
import xml.dom.minidom
import cv2
import numpy as np


def extract(file):
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(file)
    values = doc.getElementsByTagName("coordinateIndex")
    coordX = doc.getElementsByTagName("x")
    coordY = doc.getElementsByTagName("y")
    d = {}                                              # <-- That's a dictionary!
    for atr_value, atr_x, atr_y in zip(values, coordX, coordY):
        value = atr_value.getAttribute('value')
        x = float(atr_x.getAttribute('value'))          # <-- to float
        y = float(atr_y.getAttribute('value'))          # <-- to float
        d[value] = [x, y]
    return d
```

Then, we rearrange the image loading, and coordinate extracting in the script:

```py
# Read image; extract coordinates from XML
image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
dd = extract('path/to/your/file.xml')                   # <-- That's a dictionary!
```

Finally, we convert your dictionary to some NumPy array, convert the float values to some int type, and call `cv2.polylines` properly:

```py
# Convert dictionary values to int NumPy array (needed for cv2.polylines)
pts = np.array(list(dd.values())).astype(np.int32)      # <-- to int

# Draw polygon lines
image = cv2.polylines(image,
                      [pts],
                      isClosed=False,
                      color=(0, 255, 0),
                      thickness=3,
                      lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

# Show result
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I added two more points to your sample XML, and used my default test image – that's the output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Great answer! Unluckily the kaouter berrahal doesn't appreciate it. +1 from my side!